# How to make materil UI tabs label left ? by default its center aligned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

By default material ui tab label is center aligned, how do i make it left aligned ?

[center aligned tab labels image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtDWO.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can use https://codesandbox.io to create a an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help

```
.MuiTab-wrapper {
        align-items: self-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;

}
```

By default both of them are centered.

Comment: just a heads up for future references. The.MuiTab-wrapper is not used anymore. It is MuiTab-wrapped now and remember having your tabs elements wrapped={true}

Answer (score 6):

Inline is so:
<Tab sx={{alignItems: 'start',}} label="Application" {...a11yProps(0)} />

Answer (score 1):

Well, I maybe late. But someone might find it useful,

```
<Tabs
    ..otherProps
    sx={{
        '&& .MuiTab-root': {
            alignItems: 'baseline',
        },
    }}
>
```

Answer (score 1):

sx={{
".MuiTab-root":{
alignItems: "start",
},
}}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just  add `alignItems` in the `Tab` component:

```
<Tabs {...args}>
    <Tab label={name} sx={{ alignItems: 'flex-start' }} />
</Tabs>
```